# Azure bot service issue: Test in web chat not available for deployed bot

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, botframework

I deployed my bot, which works fine locally, to the azure portal and succeeded according to the msg from deployment center. But when I try to test the bot in web chat, the chat window does not show up with only an error msg 'Something went wrong, please contact the site administrator'. What may be the reason for this error and how could I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure, but emm, have you checked the configuration in bot service, including app id of azure ad app and message endpoint? Especially app id, it should match the setting in your code.

Comment: The bot was written in node.js and I did put the corresponding app id and key in the .env file. The problem is I can't talk to the bot in web chat since the whole chat window does not show up and there is nowhere I can type nor get an exact error msg indicating what has gone wrong. 

Comment: Did you test the web chat in the 'Test in Web Chat' panel in you bot service instance? If so, you could see error message in 'Channels' panel.

Comment: I did try to test the bot in 'Test in Web Chat', but couldn't talk to it. I just got enough credit to post a picture, could you see that?

Comment: Yes, I see your screenshot, and I really haven't met your problem, and can this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-bot-configuration?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#bot-does-not-work-in-web-chat) on trouble shooting help you? In my opinion, what I can suggest you is that you may create another bot instance to test if the problem comes from the creation.

Comment: I personally saw this once before...when someone deleted my Bot Service (Bot Channels Registration) but the App Service was still there. So my first thought is that there is some issue with the app service connecting to the bot service. Do you actually have a .env file on the app service? Typically those files aren't part of a push from a source control system. Typically you would set those as configuration settings within the app service. You may also want to look at the App Service Logs (under the app service, after turning them on you can view the Log Stream). See if you get any error there

Comment: @billoverton shared his experience and it seems that it really has relationship with the bot instance(bot channels registration), create a new one for testing sir?

Comment: Have you got any progress sir?

Comment: @mechabunny19c please validate microsoft appid, password, appserive url in your code + bot channel setup. If again your facing this issue the create a webapp bot with auto password option and this will defently resolve your issue.

Comment: is your issue resolved with any of the above comments? Please refer to the troubleshooting [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-bot-configuration?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) to check if its a config issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the problem leads to the error above comes from the azure bot instance(bot channel registration), as discussed in the comment, it should be better to create a new channel registration for the bot.